# Export SQL query result as a txt file to Azure blob storage automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am trying to export the result of a query to a container in the Azure blob storage. I did much research and it seems there are services that can do this, but they are paid services; is there any way to automate this without any paid service at all? I can already push the files from my computer to the storage automatically, but if I could find a way to directly do this it will be great. Essentially I want to extract some data on daily basis to the storage and make it possible for a simple download using browsers or from withing Excel

fictitious Example:

```
SELECT name, salary FROM dbo.Employees
Export to https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myresults.txt
```

Comment: I think SSIS can do this

Comment: Hi @Ibo, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use on-premise SQL Server and want to run the script which save the query result to Blob Storage automatically, SSIS is the good solution. It's free and very effective.

You can ref this tutorial [Azure Blob Storage Data Upload with SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6662/azure-blob-storage-data-upload-with-ssis/): it teaches us run a SQL query and upload it to Blob Storage.

Then you can schedule run the SSIS package with a SQL Server agent job. Ref this document: [How to Execute SSIS Packages from SQL Server Agent](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6639/execute-ssis-packages-from-sql-server-agent/):

- SSIS is indeed a good choice for implementing ETL processes. The
  typical process is scheduled to run on a periodic basis. SQL Server
  Agent is a good tool for executing SSIS packages as well as
  scheduling jobs to run at the appropriate times.

You can combine these two documents and achieve your purpose.

Comment: I am using Azure DB, let me implement this and see if it worked, I will get back to your answer. I need some time for this, thanks!

Comment: @Ibo Please clarify question or add the tag Azure SQL database. Azure SQL doesn't support sql agent. You may need create the script and schedule run with PowerShell.